# Debian NIC Bonding slow write

Tags: debian, bonding

I set up NIC bonding on my debian 8 machine as a test, and I ran into the following problem.
Without bonding I get ~90MB/s write and ~100MB/s read. After I enabled bonding the write speed dropped to around 30-35 MB/s, but reading is still around 90MB/s.

Content of my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto bond0
        iface bond0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.2 8.8.8.8
        dns-domain dev
        bond-mode 0
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-slaves eth0 eth1
        bond-updelay 200
        bond-downdelay 200
        mtu 7152
```

The server is connected to a 16 port TP-Link Gbit Switch.
I switched the cables and used another switch, but the problem persists

Tested bond-modes:
Mode 0 - read 90MB/s write 30MB/s
Mode 1 - read 100MB/s write 90MB/s
Mode 5 - read 50MB/s write 90MB/s
Mode 6 - read 90MB/s write 80MB/s

Comment: read-write operations are typically associated with disk IO and/or protocols such as iSCSI, NFS and SMB (and the disk might be the limiting factor) and for networking the jargon is mostly send/transmit and receive, so the question is what are you testing and how do you achieve those results?

Comment: I am testing the sending and transmiting rates on my server, without bonding send/transmit was like stated above. The read an write operations are done on a ssd. I got my results by using ftp and samba to copy a 5GB file from and to the server.

Comment: Are you configuring the switch appropriately for the selected bonding modes?  See section 12 of https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt